# trouble with i.landsat.toar failing to identify satellite

Tags: imagery, landsat

I am trying to use the i.landsat.toar tool on L7 bands. I have tried to use both the MTL and MTLold, but no matter what I try, it returns "Failed to identify satellite." What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the settings you have in the metadata tab by inserting a screen shot here, or you might be able to highlight and copy the command text at the bottom of the dialog window which is created by your selections.

Comment: There have been recent fixes, which version of GRASS GIS are you using?

Comment: (Sun Feb 24 09:37:15 2013)                                                      
i.landsat.toar input_prefix=LE71710822012330ASN00 output_prefix=LE71710822012330ASN00_toar metfile=G:\South Africa\Data\2012\171\LE71710822012330ASN00\LE71710822012330ASN00_MTL.txt sensor=tm7 method=corrected
WARNING: Unable to recognize satellite platform [0]
ERROR: Failed to identify satellite
(Sun Feb 24 09:37:15 2013) Command finished (0 sec)                             
(Sun Feb 24 09:48:27 2013)

Comment: This is the output that I received in the command output. I am using GRASS 6.4.3RCD on windows. I'm wondering about the 'prefix' option; I assume this is the file name excluding the band name?

Answer (score 1):

One thing I check explicitly for L5 is that the date of acquisition in the mtl/txt file matches the date of the file to be processed. You have to be aware of the naming convention of the files to do this.

I don't use a standard version of grass, but I expect the module should be the same for you, see this image

[image]

Also I just ran a Landsat 7 scene from 1999. For simplicity I treated it as Landsat 5, changing the 61 band to 6. I note that toar would not process that unless I used the mtlold.txt file which was included with scene, which I had only pulled from USGS yesterday. In that case I got the error:

> ERROR: Unknown production date (defined by 'product_date')

The successful command was:

> i.landsat.toar -t --verbose input_prefix=7_92811999348_ output_prefix=7_92811999348_toar metfile=E:\GIS_mega\7TM+ 
>   \Walgett_9281\LE70920811999348SGS01\LE70920811999348SGS01_MTLold.txt method=dos3

note the verbose option to give you some feedback.

Comment: i.landsat.toar has now been updated in GRASS GIS 6 and 7 to deal better with the various metadata.